# Problem in secure copying (scp) filenames with spaces

Tags: linux, command-line, scp

I am trying to copy files using secure copy(scp). I am trying to execute the following command but I get error due to the space in the absolute path of the location of the directory.

```
scp -r -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103:/media/New Volume/lj /home/pratheep
```

I am getting the following error:

```
scp: /media/New: No such file or directory  
scp: Volume/lj: No such file or directory
```

I tried using the same command putting extra back slash like

```
scp -r -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103:/media/New\ Volume/lj /home/pratheep
```

but I am still getting the same error.

Can somebody tell me how to correct it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should quote your file name two times, one for the local shell and one for the remote one. In the simplest case you can do one of the following

```
scp -r -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103:"'/media/New Volume/lj'" /home/pratheep
scp -r -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103:'"/media/New Volume/lj"' /home/pratheep
```

or using the help of tab completion

```
scp -r -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103:/media/New\\\ Volume/lj /home/pratheep
```

Comment: It is helpful to note that `scp` uses `ssh` as its transport which explains why there are two passes of shell interpretation happening.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` and `rsync` pass remote file names to the remote shell. This allows you to pass patterns, as in

```
scp remotehost:'*.txt' .
```

but it has the nasty consequence that you need extra quoting when supplying a remote file name.

You can pass the `-s` option to `rsync` to make it protect the file names from expansion by the remote shell. But that turns on rsync's built-in wildcard expansion, so you still need to quote `\[?*`.

A workaround is to transfer an archive:

```
ssh -P 8484 root@172.31.72.103 'cd "/media/New Volume" && tar cf - lj' |
tar xf - -C /home/pratheep
```

Another method is to mount the remote filesystem, and then use ordinary tools to perform the copy.

```
mkdir mnt
sshfs -p 8484 root@172.31.72.103:/ mnt
cp -Rp 'mnt/media/New Volume/lj' /home/pratheep
fusermount -u mnt
rmdir mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues when trying to copy files from remote paths containing spaces using `scp` from within a Bash script.

Here are the solutions I came up with:

**Escape paths manually:**

```
scp user@host:'dir\ with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces' <destination>
scp user@host:"dir\\ with\\ spaces/file\\ with\\ spaces" <destination>
scp user@host:dir\\\ with\\\ spaces/file\\\ with\\\ spaces <destination>
```

Note: does not require option `-T` (see below).

**Use double-quoting + option `-T`:**

```
scp -T user@host:"'<path-with-spaces>'" <destination>
scp -T user@host:'"<path-with-spaces>"' <destination>
scp -T user@host:"\"<path-with-spaces>\"" <destination>
```

Note: without option `-T`, these commands will result in `protocol error: filename does not match request`. The reason for this is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598689/scp-fails-with-protocol-error-filename-does-not-match-request).

**Escape path using printf:**

```
source="<path-with-spaces>"
printf -v source "%q" "${source}"
scp user@host:"${source}" <destination>
```

Note: this works fine without option `-T`, but only for a single file. For multiple files, option `-T` is required again (same error as above).