# SCP error for bash script with spaces in source path

Tags: bash, shell-script, scp

Surely I'm missing something simple, but this is driving me nuts. I'm trying to SCP a remote file to the current local directory. The remote path has spaces in it. I need this to run in a script and put the path into a variable, because it's being read from a file.

Problem is, no matter how I try to escape it, I'm still getting a "File or Directory not found" error. I put the `-v` option on the `scp` command, and the command it's sending over works if I copy and paste it, but when I have the variable in there, it blows up.

Note that it works fine if I write out the path, but breaks when I try to put the path into a variable. There's lots of similar questions for just escaping a hard coded string, but I couldn't find anything for using variables with spaces in the filepath.

Path to file is:
`/home/myUser/databases/SONIC BOATS LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip`

When running `scp` verbose, the line `sending command` prints the following:

```
 scp -f /home/myUser/databases/SONIC\\ BOATS\\ LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip .
```

If I paste that line into my script and run it, then it works. So why isn't it working when it's running in the script with the variables?

My variables print out as follows:

DB_ARC_FILENAME:

```
/home/myUser/databases/SONIC BOATS LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
```

ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME

```
/home/myUser/databases/SONIC\ BOATS\ LTD./database-19.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
```

And my script code snippet:

```
while read DB_ARC_FILENAME
do
        # Escape spaces in the files name
        ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME=${DB_ARC_FILENAME//\ /\\\ }

        # Copy the database file to the local system
        scp -v foobar@xx.xx.xx.xx:"$ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME" .
...

done < uploadedDatabaseFileList
```

Here's the output I'm getting when I run it:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /home/myUser/databases/SONIC\\ BOATS\\ LRD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
: No such file or directoryer/databases/SONIC BOATS LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
: No such file or directoryes/SONIC BOATS LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2836, received 2704 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3678.9, received 3507.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in secure copying (scp) filenames with spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31018/problem-in-secure-copying-scp-filenames-with-spaces)

Comment: No - it works if I type out the filename, the problem arises when I put the filename into a variable.

Comment: Try replacing "$ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME" with ${ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME}

Comment: @GillesQuenot I think your suggested duplicate isn't really a duplicate

Comment: That didn't change anything. I've updated my question with the output from `scp` with the verbose flag. It's the same with and without the braces.

Comment: @mkc that's worse. The double quotes were correct; your braces are not.

Comment: @mkc, @roaima: braces got nothing to do with it. Braces are necessary in certain situations, e.g. `echo "$varhello"` vs. `echo "${var}hello"`. Other than that, `$var` and `${var}` are exactly the same in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your escape pattern isn't quite right. Use this instead, which prefixes every occurrence of a space with a single backslash:

```
ESC_DB_ARC_FILENAME="${DB_ARC_FILENAME// /\\ }"
```

Test scenario (in `$HOME`):

```
file='the date.txt'
date > "$file"

scp -vp localhost:"$file" td; ls -l td; rm -f td             # Fails
scp -vp localhost:"${file// /\\ }" td; ls -l td; rm -f td    # Succeeds
```

---

Got it. This error message gives it away:

```
: No such file or directoryes/SONIC BOATS LTD./database-1.11-2019-12-30-09-40.zip
```

You're using a source data file generated on a Windows machine. The trailing CR is being seen as part of the filename, and of course your source file doesn't have such a character.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the debug output or the result - i.e. I still can't get the file. I've tried playing with the escape pattern - the one in the question is just where I ended up.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you've double-quoted the variable when it's being used? Also... does the test scenario that I've provided work for you? If not we need to dig harder.

Comment: @TonyShepherd it's your source data file

Comment: That was it. That makes no sense since the source file was generated on a linux system. But dos2unix fixed the problem. I guess I learned something new today. Thank you!!

Comment: What tool generated it?

Comment: the command I used to generate the file was this `ssh -t foobar@xx.xx.xx.xx 'find /home/myUser/databases/ -mtime -14 | grep .zip' > uploadedDatabaseFileList
`

Comment: @TonyShepherd It's the `-t` in the ssh command that caused this to happen to you. Compare the output of `ssh -t foobar@xx.xx.xx.xx date | hexdump -Cv` with the output of `ssh foobar@xx.xx.xx.xx date | hexdump -Cv`.  The former will have `0d0a` line-endings, the latter won't.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues when trying to copy files from remote paths containing spaces using `scp` from within a Bash script.

Here are the solutions I came up with:

**Use double-quoting + option `-T`:**

```
scp -T user@host:"'<path-with-spaces>'" <destination>
scp -T user@host:'"<path-with-spaces>"' <destination>
scp -T user@host:"\"<path-with-spaces>\"" <destination>
```

Note: without option `-T`, these commands will result in `protocol error: filename does not match request`. The reason for this is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598689/scp-fails-with-protocol-error-filename-does-not-match-request).

**Escape path using printf:**

```
source="<path-with-spaces>"
printf -v source "%q" "${source}"
scp user@host:"${source}" <destination>
```

Note: this works fine without option `-T`, but only for a single file. For multiple files, option `-T` is required again (same error as above).